# Show "out of stock" label when product is on backorders in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, stock

In Woocommerce, regarding products stock availability displayed text, I'm looking for a way to show the "Out of stock" text even when allow backorder is activated, without require notification.

How can I show "out of stock" label when product is on backorders in Woocommerce?
I'm using storefront theme

Comment: Don't add a comment as an answer as I don't get notified, below my answer there is a comment zone… As a new user [get the quick tour (30 seconds)](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to better understand StackOverFlow basically. The is no stock label displayed by default on woocommerce archive pages, so you are using a custom code or a plugin: Add this related information in your question.

Comment: I'm using storefront theme.

Answer (score 4):

Woocommerce allows you to enable backorders with or without notification. When backorder notification is enabled the text "Available on backorder" is displayed and nothing for without notification.

When products are on backorder, the following will display the text *"Out of stock (can be backordered)"*, when backorder is enabled without notifications:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability_text', 'custom_backorders_stock_availability_text', 10, 2 );
function custom_backorders_stock_availability_text( $availability, $product ) {
    if ( $product->managing_stock() && $product->is_on_backorder( 1 ) ) {
        if ( ! $product->backorders_require_notification() ) {
            $availability = __( 'Out of stock (can be backordered)', 'woocommerce' );
        }
    }
    return $availability;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

**Product settings *(on inventory tab)*:**

[image]

**Stock availability displayed text *(when it's in backorders)*:**

[image]

---

Or for all cases when product is on backorders *(even with notification)*, use instead:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability_text', 'custom_backorders_stock_availability_text', 10, 2 );
function custom_backorders_stock_availability_text( $availability, $product ) {
    if ( $product->managing_stock() && $product->is_on_backorder( 1 ) ) {
        $availability = __( 'Out of stock (can be backordered)', 'woocommerce' );
    }
    return $availability;
}
```

Comment: Thank You @loictheaztec but if we have backordered for a variable the above it doesn't work.