# Change WooCommerce backorder message is allow or allow but notify

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, stock

I'm using [Show “out of stock” label when product is on backorders in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53935566/11987538) answer code. (second part)

But is it possible to have a different message if I select "allow but notify" instead of "allow"?

I don't know how can i test if the  backorder is allow or allowed with notification.

Comment: You could use for "Allow" = [`$product->backorders_allowed()`](https://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_productbackorders_allowed/), "Notify" = [`$product->backorders_require_notification()`](https://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_productbackorders_require_notification/) 
. If (one of) these are true you can adjust your message based on that

Comment: If I use "$product->backorders_allowed()" the allow message is overwride with this message too. :(

Comment: You are using existing code (second part), however, it consists of 2 answers. I believe if you use the first part it will answer your question right away. 
If not, search for [woocommerce_get_availability_text](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=woocommerce_get_availability_text). There are anyway related questions + answers to find with which you can answer your own question

Answer (score 0):

This code works, If it can help someone:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability_text', 'custom_backorders_stock_availability_text1', 10, 2 );
function custom_backorders_stock_availability_text1( $availability, $product ) {
    // Managing stock & product is on backorder (true)
    if ( $product->managing_stock() && $product->is_on_backorder() ) {
        
        // Backorder with allow (true)
        if ( $product->backorders_allowed() ) {
            $availability = __( 'Disponible sous 10 jours', 'woocommerce' );
            
            // Backorder with allow AND notify (true)
            if ( $product->backorders_require_notification() ) {
                $availability = __( 'Délai 4 à 5 semaines', 'woocommerce' );
            }
        }
    }
    
    return $availability;
}
```